# java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a timestamp from cloud firestore and store it in a date variable but I am getting this exception :

```
java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

this is the code for getting the value from the cloud firestore :

```
Date timeStamp = (Date) dataSnapshot.get("date");
```

and this is the code for storing the date in the database :

```
map.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

I can't figure out how to solve this error

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement? `map.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: If you want to insert current time, to be retrieved back as a `java.util.Date` object, why not `map.put("date", new Date());`?

Answer (score 1):

[ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP) is of type `HashMap<String,String>`. 
That's what you are saving here: `map.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`.
When you do `dataSnapshot.get("date");`,  that's what will be returned. If you stored date as a string, you'll have to manually get it from the `HashMap`.

Comment: How can I get it ?

Comment: I know how to use it but I don't know how can I use it to get the value here please update your answer with the code and I will accept it